# How many dots do you get for Paths in Trinity Continuum

Tags: character-creation, storypath, trinity-continuum, scion-2e

So, the second editions of both Scion and the Trinity games use Onyx Path's new Storypath system, and I'm trying to wrap my head around the character creation, which is made a bit more difficult thanks to the lack of a "summary" page that lists the total number of dots you get for each kind of stat you have.

In the Trinity Continuum book, it says that your Paths are ranked by the number of dots in them, but I can't see anywhere where it says how many dots you get in Paths, and you get three skill points per Path dot. In Scion 2e, you rank your Paths into primary/secondary/tertiary, and you get three skill points per level of category - primary gives you nine, secondary gives you six, and tertiary gives you three.

Do you get six dots of Paths in Trinity Continuum to mirror the ranking of paths in Scion, or do you get one dot in each Path? Scion's Birthrights and Trinity Continuum's Edges seem to be broadly analogous, and you get two dots of Edges per Path dot, and one dot in each path would give you six Edge dots, which would be similar to Scion's seven Birthright dots.

Is the intention that ordinary humans in Scion are simply more broadly capable than ordinary humans in Trinity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pg. 36, *Trinity Continuum* core rulebook, second emphasis mine:

> In **Trinity Continuum** each character has three Paths: Origin, Role, and Society. Each Path is signifcant to the character and reﬂects a major commitment of her time. A Path can be a single word or a short phrase that summarizes the nature of the character’s experiences. **Players begin the game with one dot in each of their three Paths.**

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!